# having trouble in increasing value of prefab by PlayerPrefs Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to increase the value of a prefab(the prefab is instantiating when the game starts) when the load to next scene but I'm having trouble loading value with increment using `playerprefs`.

this is where I'm setting the value of player prefs in `GunScript.cs`

`GunScript.cs`

```
void Awake() {
  PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Inaccuracy", inaccuracy);
  Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Inaccuracy"));
}
```

and whenever I click on the next button the same scene loaded and I want this inaccuracy vale to be increased by 2 in LevelLoad.cs script.

`LevelLoad.cs`

```
public void OnNext(){
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Inaccuracy", 
    PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Inaccuracy") + 2);
    print(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Inaccuracy"));
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}
```

it is printing increment value but no increasing value in the `prefab`.

Comment: You definitely should not use PlayerPrefs for that kind of stuff, it's not meant to be constantly updated at runtime. Why aren't you using something like a singleton, static variable or whatever ?

Comment: This line is not valid: `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Inaccuracy") + 2);` you have only one `(`, but two `)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this approach, it stores the value into a temp variable, performs the calculation and then updates the player pref.

```
public void OnNext()
{
   float previousValue = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Inaccuracy", 0); //0 is the default
   float newValue = previousValue + 2f;

   PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Inaccuracy", newValue);
   print(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Inaccuracy"));    

}
```